# ImportError: No module named google.oauth2 (Service Account)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-import, google-oauth, service-accounts

When importing

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
```

I get this error

```
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\runtime\sandbox.py", line 1174, in load_module
    raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
ImportError: No module named google.oauth2
```

I installed google cloud SDK.
Lib folder for my project containing

```
google
google-api-core
google-api-python-client
google-auth
google-auth-httplib2
google-cloud-bigquery
google-cloud-pubsub
google-cloud-core
google-resumable-media
googleapis-common-protos
```

I was wondering what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you specified the folder where all the libraries will be installed? As per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring), in your `appengine_conffig.py` you have to specify which is the libraries folder:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')
```

Also sometimes the error can happen if the libraries are installed both in the project folder and in the python local libs folder (usually located at `/usr/local/python2.7/dist-packages`). You can try removing both library folders and installing the libraries in your GAE project folder.

```
pip install -t lib -r requirements.txt --upgrade
```